# How to use jquery hover for a div and an html tag inside the same div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to jquery, I have been trying to use the .hover event but i got this issues and i have not found my way around it. what i want to do is when i hove a div i want to add a border-color to that div which i have been able to do and at the same time i will also like to have the h4 tag to change color while the image to have a change like an opacity on the image with some text.

```
<div class="layout">
            <div class="col-1 welcomediv">
                <img src="images/electricalinstallation.png" class=" img-responsive" alt="Image">
                <div class="col-1-text">
                    <div  class="wh4">
                        <h4>My head 1</h4>
                    </div>
                    <center>
                        <hr class="col-1-hr">
                    </center>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut tempore asperiores veniam ex laborum, repellendus perspiciatis itaque at deleniti esse nostrum facere eveniet reiciendis! Nulla veniam ea culpa repellat odio.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 welcomediv">
                <div class="col-1-text">
                    <div  class="wh4">
                        <h4>My head 2</h4>
                    </div>
                    <center>
                        <hr class="col-1-hr">
                    </center>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut tempore asperiores veniam ex laborum, repellendus perspiciatis itaque at deleniti esse nostrum facere eveniet reiciendis! Nulla veniam ea culpa repellat odio.</p>
                </div>
                <img src="images/Transformer_Installation.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Image">
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 welcomediv">
                <img src="images/House-Wiring.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Image">
                <div class="col-1-text">
                    <div  class="wh4">
                        <h4>My head 3</h4>
                    </div>

                    <center>
                        <hr class="col-1-hr">
                    </center>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut tempore asperiores veniam ex laborum, repellendus perspiciatis itaque at deleniti esse nostrum facere eveniet reiciendis! Nulla veniam ea culpa repellat odio.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

jquery code

```
$('.welcomediv').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('col-1hover');
    $('.wh4').addClass('col-1-texhover');
  },
  function(){
    $(this).removeClass('col-1hover');
    $('.wh4').removeClass('col-1-texhover');
  });
```

CSS code

```
.col-1-texhover {
   color:#f7b72f;
 }
.col-1hover {
   border-color: #f7b72f;
 }
```

i will really like your help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a special reason why you want to do this with jQuery instead of just CSS (`.welcomediv:hover { border-color: ... } .welcomediv:hover .wh4 { color: ... }`)?

Comment: i want to hover on the that div and get three effect at the same time. if i use css i will have to go on the element it self

Comment: i don't want to have to go on each element

Comment: This part is not apparent from your description/question.

Comment: If Pranavs solution works then it will also work with the CSS only solution I mentioned in my first comment o.O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the element within the hovered element, either you can specify [context with jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context) or use [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method.

```
$('.welcomediv').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('col-1hover');
    $('.wh4', this).addClass('col-1-texhover');
    // -----^^^^^----- here or $(this).find('.wh4')
  },
  function() {
    $(this).removeClass('col-1hover');
    $('.wh4', this).removeClass('col-1-texhover');
  });
```

```js
$('.welcomediv').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('col-1hover');
    $('.wh4', this).addClass('col-1-texhover');
  },
  function() {
    $(this).removeClass('col-1hover');
    $('.wh4', this).removeClass('col-1-texhover');
  });
```

```css
.col-1-texhover {
  color: #f7b72f;
}

.col-1hover {
  border: solid 1px #f7b72f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="layout">
  <div class="col-1 welcomediv">
    <img src="images/electricalinstallation.png" class=" img-responsive" alt="Image">
    <div class="col-1-text">
      <div class="wh4">
        <h4>My head 1</h4>
      </div>
      <center>
        <hr class="col-1-hr">
      </center>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut tempore asperiores veniam ex laborum, repellendus perspiciatis itaque at deleniti esse nostrum facere eveniet reiciendis! Nulla veniam ea culpa repellat odio.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1 welcomediv">
    <div class="col-1-text">
      <div class="wh4">
        <h4>My head 2</h4>
      </div>
      <center>
        <hr class="col-1-hr">
      </center>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut tempore asperiores veniam ex laborum, repellendus perspiciatis itaque at deleniti esse nostrum facere eveniet reiciendis! Nulla veniam ea culpa repellat odio.</p>
    </div>
    <img src="images/Transformer_Installation.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Image">
  </div>
  <div class="col-1 welcomediv">
    <img src="images/House-Wiring.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Image">
    <div class="col-1-text">
      <div class="wh4">
        <h4>My head 3</h4>
      </div>

      <center>
        <hr class="col-1-hr">
      </center>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut tempore asperiores veniam ex laborum, repellendus perspiciatis itaque at deleniti esse nostrum facere eveniet reiciendis! Nulla veniam ea culpa repellat odio.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

You can do the same thing with pure CSS as well using [`:hover` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover).

```
.welcomediv:hover .wh4 {
  color: #f7b72f;
}

.welcomediv:hover {
  border: 1px solid #f7b72f;
}
```

```css
.welcomediv:hover .wh4 {
  color: #f7b72f;
}

.welcomediv:hover {
  border: 1px solid #f7b72f;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="col-1 welcomediv">
    <img src="images/electricalinstallation.png" class=" img-responsive" alt="Image">
    <div class="col-1-text">
      <div class="wh4">
        <h4>My head 1</h4>
      </div>
      <center>
        <hr class="col-1-hr">
      </center>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut tempore asperiores veniam ex laborum, repellendus perspiciatis itaque at deleniti esse nostrum facere eveniet reiciendis! Nulla veniam ea culpa repellat odio.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1 welcomediv">
    <div class="col-1-text">
      <div class="wh4">
        <h4>My head 2</h4>
      </div>
      <center>
        <hr class="col-1-hr">
      </center>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut tempore asperiores veniam ex laborum, repellendus perspiciatis itaque at deleniti esse nostrum facere eveniet reiciendis! Nulla veniam ea culpa repellat odio.</p>
    </div>
    <img src="images/Transformer_Installation.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Image">
  </div>
  <div class="col-1 welcomediv">
    <img src="images/House-Wiring.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Image">
    <div class="col-1-text">
      <div class="wh4">
        <h4>My head 3</h4>
      </div>

      <center>
        <hr class="col-1-hr">
      </center>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut tempore asperiores veniam ex laborum, repellendus perspiciatis itaque at deleniti esse nostrum facere eveniet reiciendis! Nulla veniam ea culpa repellat odio.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: let me try out the image